Implementing Undo/Redo Functionality in img.ly PESDK Flutter After Saving Edited Images
I am working on a Flutter project where I'm using the img.ly PhotoEditor SDK (PESDK) to edit images picked via an image picker. After applying filters and saving the edited image with serialization, I'm facing an issue with implementing undo and redo functionality for subsequent edits.
Here's a step-by-step scenario of what I'm trying to achieve:

I pick multiple images and videos using an image picker.
Upon selecting an image (let's say image 1), I open it in the img.ly PESDK editor.
I apply filters and adjustments to image 1 and save it using serialization.
I repeat the same editing process for other images.
Later, I decide that I want to revert image 1 to its original (filterless) state.
I open image 1 again in the editor, but there's undo or redo functionality available to revert back to the original one i.e before saving it.

Question:
How can I implement undo and redo functionality in img.ly PESDK Flutter after saving an edited image with serialization? I want to be able to revert back to a previous state (e.g., filterless) even after saving the image.
Below is a simplified version of the relevant Flutter code I'm using:
UI
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:photo_editor_sdk/photo_editor_sdk.dart';
import 'package:tymelyne/AddPosts/photoEditingConfig.dart';
import 'package:tymelyne/Universal/Widgets/UniversalWidgets.dart';
import 'package:video_editor_sdk/video_editor_sdk.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

//
class SelectedMediaScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<XFile> selectedMediaList;

  const SelectedMediaScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectedMediaList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SelectedMediaScreen> createState() => _SelectedMediaScreenState();
}

class _SelectedMediaScreenState extends State<SelectedMediaScreen> {
  /// Generates thumbnail for video files
  Future<String> _generateThumbnail(String videoPath) async {
    final thumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
      video: videoPath,
      thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
      maxHeight: 200,
      quality: 75,
    );
    return thumbnail!;
  }

  //
  List _serList = [];

  /// Handle photo editing
  Future<void> _handlePhotoEdit({required int fileIndex}) async {
    try {
      // //
      String serializationPath = "abc.json";

      // Load the serialization from the provided file path.
      final serializationFile = File(serializationPath);
      final serializationString = await serializationFile.readAsString();
      final serialization = jsonDecode(serializationString);

      // Opens photo editor
      await PESDK
          .openEditor(
        image: widget.selectedMediaList[fileIndex].path,
        configuration: createConfiguration(),
        serialization: serialization,
      )
          .then(
        (result) {
          setState(
            () {
              // Replaces the original file with newly edited
              widget.selectedMediaList[fileIndex] = XFile(
                Uri.parse(result!.image).path,
              );

              // Adds serialization as an object (Currently using fileUrl serialization)
              _serList.add(result.serialization as Map<String, dynamic>?);
            },
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(error);
      }
    }
  }

  /// Handle video editing
  Future<void> _handleVideoEdit({required int fileIndex}) async {
    try {
      await VESDK
          .openEditor(
            Video(widget.selectedMediaList[fileIndex].path),
            // configuration: createConfiguration(),
          )
          .then(
            (result) => setState(() {
              widget.selectedMediaList[fileIndex] = XFile(
                Uri.parse(result!.video).path,
              );
            }),
          );
    } catch (error) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(error);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        centerTitle: true,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
        title: Text(
          '${widget.selectedMediaList.length} files',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.tealAccent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  15,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                  vertical: 1.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Next',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 8.0,
          vertical: 15.0,
        ),
        child: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            childAspectRatio: 1.0, // For a square aspect ratio
          ),
          itemCount: widget.selectedMediaList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            XFile mediaFile = widget.selectedMediaList[index];
            return FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: mediaFile.path.endsWith('.mp4') ||
                      mediaFile.path.endsWith('.mov')
                  ? _generateThumbnail(mediaFile.path)
                  : Future.value(mediaFile.path),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.error,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: mediaFile.path.endsWith('.mp4') ||
                            mediaFile.path.endsWith('.mov')
                        ? GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => _handleVideoEdit(fileIndex: index),
                            child: Stack(
                              fit: StackFit.expand,
                              children: [
                                //
                                Image.file(
                                  File(snapshot.data!),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),

                                const Icon(
                                  Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                                  size: 45,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        : GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => _handlePhotoEdit(fileIndex: index),
                            child: Stack(
                              fit: StackFit.expand,
                              children: [
                                //
                                Image.file(
                                  File(mediaFile.path),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Config:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:imgly_sdk/imgly_sdk.dart' as imgly;

imgly.Configuration createConfiguration() {
  // Serialization
  final serializationOptions = imgly.SerializationOptions(
    enabled: true,
    exportType: imgly.SerializationExportType.fileUrl,
  );

  final configuration = imgly.Configuration(
    // Top bar position
    toolbarMode: imgly.ToolbarMode.top,

    // Tools arrangement
    tools: [
      imgly.Tool.filter,
      imgly.Tool.transform,
      imgly.Tool.adjustment,
      imgly.Tool.text,
      imgly.Tool.textDesign,
      imgly.Tool.brush,
      imgly.Tool.sticker,
      imgly.Tool.overlay,
      imgly.Tool.frame,
      imgly.Tool.focus,
    ],

    //
    export: imgly.ExportOptions(
      serialization: serializationOptions,
      image: imgly.ImageOptions(
        exportType: imgly.ImageExportType.fileUrl,
      ),
    ),

    //

    // Theme
    theme: imgly.ThemeOptions(
      imgly.Theme(
        "custom_theme_identifier",
        primaryColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        toolbarBackgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        menuBackgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        tintColor: Colors.tealAccent,
      ),
    ),
  );

  return configuration;
}

